# Get list of users who contacted my Facebook Messenger Page

Tags: facebook, platform, messenger

I am building a Chat Bot using Facebook Messenger Platform.

According to Facebook documentation, all users who previously contacted my page via Messenger chat can be contacted using the bot.

My question is: is there a way to retrieve the list of user ids who previously contacted my page on Messenger, previous to the bot being enabled on the page?

My intention is to engage them and let them know that they can use the bot now.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does it say that you can message anyone that previously messaged your page?

Comment: @WizKid i am sure i've read it somewhere, but at this point the only thing that confirms that a bot can contact a user who has previously messaged a business is the Messenger Platform FAQ:

"All experiences in Messenger are opted into by people via one of the following actions:

- Send a message to a business in Messenger
- Tap “Get Started” from a businesses' Messenger Welcome Screen
- Agree to get updates from a business, like during checkout on their website via a plugin or signing up for SMS alerts"